# A heap has been corrupted on realloc()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to write a common function to resize and concatenate strings but on calling realloc() a runtime exception occurs stating a heap has been corrupted.

```
//two string pointer initialized with malloc()
wchar_t* stream;
wchar_t* toAdd;

stream = (WCHAR *)malloc(sizeof(wchar) );
toAdd= (WCHAR *)malloc(sizeof(wchar) );

//function declaration
int ReallocStringCat(wchar_t *, const wchar_t *);

//
int ReallocStringCat(wchar_t *dest,const  wchar_t *source)
{
    //below line throws a heap corrupt exception
    *dest =(wchar_t) realloc(dest, wcslen(dest) + wcslen(source) + 1);
    return  wcscat_s(stream,wcslen(dest) + wcslen(source) + 1, source);
}
```

I"m sure that I'm wrong somewhere in using with pointers and addresses but not able to figure out.

Also is there any inbuilt function like mutable classes available in Visual Studio 2012 C++ for native Win32 C++ applications without any CLR/MFC/ATL libraries?

Comment: First, `realloc` returns pointer to memory block. If you'd like to change `dest` for caller you need to pass `wchar_t * *` and change typecast to `wchar_t *` before `realloc`. If not, then it's `dest = (wchar_t *) realloc( ... )`. Second, `realloc` needs number of bytes, not number of symbols. `wcslen` returns number of multi-byte symbols, if I recall correctly.

Comment: This sort of mess is why experienced programmers say use std::string (or std::wstring). Are you willing to give them a go yet?

Comment: That does it, more than 2 hrs spent by a .NET developer for just concatenating two strings.
std::string seems something familiar with intellisense :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide byte size instead of number of wchar_t into realloc:

```
dest =(wchar_t *) realloc(dest, (wcslen(dest) + wcslen(source) + 1)*sizeof(wchar_t ));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
*dest =(wchar_t) realloc(dest, wcslen(dest) + wcslen(source) + 1);
```

should be

```
dest =(wchar_t*) realloc(dest, sizeof(wchar_t ) * ( wcslen(dest) + wcslen(source) + 1) );
```

You are also creating a memory leak since `dest` is being changed and not returned by function.

Comment: tried that, still getting same exception. In fact just calling below line without assigning the return value throws exception.
    realloc(dest, wcslen(dest) + wcslen(source) + 1);

Comment: dest and source might not be null terminated.

Comment: Yes Armin, both dest and source are null terminated, but shouldn't wcscat_s() take care of that?

Comment: wcscat_s is called after wcslen.

Comment: The `dst = realloc(dst, newsize)` notation leaks memory if `realloc()` fails and returns 0.  You need to use `void *space = realloc(dst, newsize); if (space != 0) { dst = space; size = newsize; }` to avoid that leak.